# Unity Firebase fails on load: "Failed to read Firebase options from the app's resources."

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Android build fails to initialise Firebase Messaging with the following error:

```
I/Unity   (30673): InitializationException: Failed to read Firebase options from the app's resources.  You'll need to either at least set App ID and API key or include google-services.json your app's resources.
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.CreateDelegate createDelegate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging+Listener..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging+Listener.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (30673): Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging
```

I have downloaded and placed the `google-services.json` file in the project root and a `google-services.xml` file has been generated in `Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values` that looks to have all the required values.

Also running the Google Play Games package if that would make any difference. Unity 5.3 and Firebase 4.1. Had it running in the past but had to re-install the packages and not working now.

Comment: Hi Firebase, developer here. have you reproduced the issue with our sample code?  I'm surprised this is happening as the xml file was generated which suggests it should be picked up by Unity's Android build unless you deleted the boilerplate project in the Plugins/Android/Firebase folder.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -
I was getting the same error on initialisation, in Unity. Key difference here was, I was using my own gradle for build, and the values inside Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values.xml was not getting merged with final values.xml

Solution:
Edited my gradle to include Firebase/res folder also to the res folders - Added following lines in mainTemplate.gradle under android block

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
                res.srcDirs += 'Firebase/res'
        }
}
```

Debugging Steps:
 1. Verified google-services.xml inside Plugins folder
 2. After building, verified the values inside Temp/ folder in Unity project
 3. Found, the values inside Temp/Firebase is not in the main generated values.xml
 4. Added line in mainTemplate.gradle to include Firebaes/res